# Class and Dict why are they not merging?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to append a dictionary in to a list but have found no luck since the range of the list/dict is unknown, this is the code:

```
def something():
    my_dict = {}
    my_list = []
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                my_dict[i,j] = False
                my_list[i,j].append(my_dict[i,j]) 
    return(my_list, my_dict)
```

Have I writen something wrong?

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code. Try searching for list and dict usage in python. While posting on SO it is recommended to put in a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: What is `n`? Where is it defined? And also: dictionaries are normally pairs of (key, value) elements. What do you mean with `dict[i,j]`? You want one to be the key and the other to be the value?

Comment: Sorry forgot to clarify its def something(n). I meant to use i,j as coordinates like a list  and set them to false like this  [1,0] = False

Comment: Then why do you need also a dictionary? Why not using only a list?

Comment: Can you please write expected output, you are looking for 1d list of dics or 2d list of dicts?

Comment: We are asked to do it in that way. Use a dictionary to print the {locations = False}, and in the next step change the value of random locations to true but in a different programm. That's why I though using a list would help me

Comment: for something(3):  {(0, 0): False, (0, 1): False, (0, 2): False, (1, 0): False, (1, 1): False, (1, 2): False, (2, 0): False, (2, 1): False, (2, 2): False}

Comment: Thanks, now it is more clear and accurate, please check if the answer satisfies your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your update, please check the below code, I think this is what you're looking for.

> **Note:** Creating dictionary before for loop (as you have mentioned in your problem will add 1 more statement to clear the dictionary after append operation, so it is better to use `my_dict = {(i, j) = False` to resolve this issue.

#### To get as a list »

```
def something(n):
    my_list = []

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            my_dict = {(i, j): False}
            my_list.append(my_dict) 

    return(my_list) # Return list

print(something(3))

"""
[{(0, 0): False}, {(0, 1): False}, {(0, 2): False}, {(1, 0): False}, {(1, 1): F
alse}, {(1, 2): False}, {(2, 0): False}, {(2, 1): False}, {(2, 2): False}]
"""
```

#### To get as a dictionary »

```
def something(n):
    my_dict = {}

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            my_dict[(i, j)] = False

    return(my_dict) # Return dictionary

print(something(3))

"""
{(0, 0): False, (0, 1): False, (0, 2): False, (1, 0): False, (1, 1): False, (1,
 2): False, (2, 0): False, (2, 1): False, (2, 2): False}
"""
```

Comment: May I ask, what changes when using the parenthesis in my_dict ?  Or is that just how it is written and I was doing it wrong?

Comment: In python, only immutable data types like, int, float, tuple like `(i, j)` & string should be used as keys. You can't use lists `[i, j]` as keys.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think about given your input is to use only a dictionary whose keys are tuple with the indexes:

```
def something(n):
    my_dict = {}
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):         
            my_dict[(i,j)] = False            
    return(my_dict)
```

If you then run:

```
d = something(3)
print(d)
```

It will output:

```
{(0, 1): False, (1, 2): False, (0, 0): False, (2, 1): False, (1, 1): False, (2, 0): False, (2, 2): False, (1, 0): False
 (0, 2): False}
```

If you want to access a single element of the dictionary you need to use:

```
d[(1,1)]
```

So for example:

```
print(d[(1,1)])
```

will output:

```
False
```